# Not able to hide Soft Keyboard for EditTextPreference

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, preferenceactivity

I have an EditText in a custom xml layout which get loaded dynamically(setView) in an EditTextPreference. Everything works well. Now when the preference is clicked and the editPreference dialog shows up, so does the soft keyboard. I dont want the soft keyboard to show up by default!

This is what I have tried. Should have worked :(!

```
public class ReportBugPreference extends EditTextPreference {


        @Override
        protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(AlertDialog.Builder builder) {
            super.onPrepareDialogBuilder(builder);  

            View viewBugReport = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.preference_report_bug,null);
            builder.setView(viewBugReport);

            EditText edttxtBugDesc = (EditText) viewBugReport.findViewById(R.id.bug_description_edittext);
            //edttxtBugDesc.clearFocus();

            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edttxtBugDesc.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);

        }

}
```

Comment: you mean when user tap on EditText then Soft keyboard will show ?am i right?

Comment: Nope! EditText has focus by default and therefore the softKeyboard shows up automatically

Comment: so you don't want soft keyboard to open by default.

Comment: Haven't you try `android:focusable` attribute and `android:focusableInTouchMode` in your XML file? If I understood the question correctly, I think you can achieve what you want from XML file rather than hard coding.

Answer (score 1):

Do this for your EditText to hide Soft-Keyboard

```
       mEditText.requestFocus();
       mEditText.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager)
                    getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    keyboard.hideSoftInputFromWindow(ettext.
                                                       getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
            },200);
```

i think more better way to do this is below Code :

```
    mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    mEditText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
             mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Works but the workaround is a bad user experience. The keyboard shows up and then hides back. Doesnt look neat! Nevertheless +1. Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

generic function that may help;

```
 public static void hideSoftKeyboard (Context context, View view) {
        try {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.w(TAG, "hideSoftKeyboard->"+ex.toString());
        }
    }
```